Defining specific class functionality using decorators as information about class overrides
I have implemented a TypeScript class Decorator function which allows me to decorate classes of the same kind. If Decorator is present above some class, that class should look into Decorator stored values for highest priority class of that kind. If newly decorated class has smaller priority of currently stored highest priority class, that new class should become that stored class.
In other words, all decorated classes of some kind should become the same as highest priority class.
Let's say I have GeneralClassA(priority 0), SpecificClassA(priority 1) and ClassA(priority 0).
All classes should point to the same class, and that's the SpecificClassA, because it has highest priority.
The plan is to have General classes already predefined and decorated, but allow the developer to define Specific class and decorate it as a higher priority class.
Everything works correctly, but the issue I have is that decorated highest priority class must be declared BEFORE all other decorated classes. Otherwise, decorated classes, declared BEFORE the highest priority class, won't be overridden.

Is there a way to retroactively override all decorated classes (I can store their constructors), once the higher priority class gets declared and decorated? Or somehow declare all Specific classes before everything?

I have replicated my problem here: StackBlitz
I have tried to store all of my decorated classes, and once the higher priority class got decorated, I tried to Object.assign one constuctor and prototype to another. That didn't work, and even if it did, what if I already used the lower priority class somewhere before I even declared higher priority class (class declaration only happens once the class is being used somewhere, at import).
I would like to get a suggestion how to initialize (declare) all Specific classes before everything, maybe even before main.js file ever get's executed.
The decorator in question:
export const YIELD_LIST: {
  [name: string]: { ctor: any; priority: number };
} = {};

type Constructable<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export function Yield<T extends Constructable<any>>(
  name: string,
  priority: number = 0
) {
  return (ctor: T) => {
    if (!YIELD_LIST[name]) {
      YIELD_LIST[name] = { ctor, priority };
    } else {
      if (YIELD_LIST[name].priority <= priority) {
        YIELD_LIST[name] = { ctor, priority };
      }
    }
    const maxPriorityCtor = YIELD_LIST[name].ctor as T;

    return class extends maxPriorityCtor {
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args);
      }
    };
  };
}


Usage:
@Yield('CLASS_A', 1)
export class SpecificClassA extends GeneralClassA {
  public override value = 10;
}


Please post the code of (at least) the decorator that does the storing of classes and comparing of priorities in the question itself, not just a link to an external site

I have edited my question, the decorator code has been added.

"If newly decorated class has smaller priority of currently stored highest priority class, that new class should become that stored class." - do I understand correctly that you want the decorator to actually replace the class being declared (by some other, stored class), not just register the class that is being declared?

Yes. I want to replace that class completely , thus the decorator returns a new class extended from the stored max priority class constructor.

This is quite weird and will probably cause a lot of surprises. Or do you want to have only 1 predefined fallback and maybe 1 developer-specified override per name? Then you probably shouldn't go with with an arbitrary-priority system.

Where (and when) are those classed being used? How do you ensure in general that all classes with decorators are loaded before using the registry?

The plan is to use it in a multiple game environment. I want to define some basic functionality in common part of the game "engine", and later add specific functionality to some of those engine classes without changing those classes directly. It's a dependency injection without the injector and "provideClass" calls - all automatic based on decorator.

I would strongly recommend not to mix "provideClass" with "useClass" functionality. Also I still don't understand why you need a complicated priority system for this.

"Or do you want to have only 1 predefined fallback and maybe 1 developer-specified override per name?" Yes. One base class and probably one developer-specified override. For example I would have "Speech" class and "MaleSpeech" class derived, both with default priority of 0. When a developer makes a new game, he can implement "FemaleSpeech" class and decorate it with priority 1. Now, for that game, engine will use that new class instead. For me, DI is much more complicated system and with this, I'm trying to accomplish simplicity.

Really for simplicity you should drop that priority. Have the developer only write import { Speech, Yield } from 'engine'; @Yield('Speech') class FemaleSpeech extends Speech { … }. Then when your engine needs a speech instance, it can check whether the developer registered their own class for that, or fall back to MaleSpeech instead.

You don't need any logic for @Yield('Speech', 0.5) class FemaleSpeech { … } to either automatically derive Speech, or to return MaleSpeech if the priority was too low.

I understand that, I like the idea of not having the priority and just directly say what you need to override. I could even use the class itself as a parameter, instead of string "Speech". The only problem is that I don't want to make it complicated by having an instance maker - I want "new Speech()" to work as normal, just the internals of Speech class to actually be FemaleSpeech or MaleSpeech.

You can't have Speech as both the factory that produces the instance of the specific class, and as the superclass of the specific implementations. This doesn't even have anything to do with dependency injection, it wouldn't work with normally defined classes either. Maybe inheritance is the wrong choice there anyway? But really I think there is nothing wrong with having a separate "instance maker". You can still write it as const MySpeech = instanceMaker('speech'); new MySpeech().

I understand that I cannot have superclass redefined. That would force a class to be derived from itself. Check the comments in StackBlitz example, I'm okay with having no override for super classes, and that is the default behavior, since that super class will always be defined first, before the derived class, and it will never even be in the consideration for override. Base class would be, in this example that we're speaking, the MaleSpeech class.

I'm sorry for spam or any confusion I caused. I have made a way of forcing a Yield class declaration first, which also forces the developer to use the Yield decorator in only one and intended way. Check it at StackBlitz if you're interested. Also, thank you for your input, it made me think more about the simplicity of the usage!

I've made it work as intended with some decorator checker logic. Developer must define all expected override classes, and all those classes must be set as overriders in order for code to even run. Override and overridden class must be decorated using Yield and Yieldable decorator functions respectively.
export const YIELD_LIST: {
  [token: string]: { overrideCtor: any };
} = {};

const EXPECTED_YIELDERS: string[] = [];
const DEFINED_YIELDERS: string[] = [];
function checkYielders() {
  if (!DEFINED_YIELDERS.every((v) => EXPECTED_YIELDERS.includes(v))) {
    throw new Error(
      'Unexpected Yielder was defined. Please add all expected Yielders in main.ts.'
    );
  }

  if (!EXPECTED_YIELDERS.every((v) => DEFINED_YIELDERS.includes(v))) {
    throw new Error(
      'Not all expected Yielders from main.ts were defined. Please Yield all expected Yielders.'
    );
  }
}

export function expectYieders<T extends Constructable<any>>(...ctors: T[]) {
  EXPECTED_YIELDERS.push(...ctors.map((x) => x.name));
  return { checkYielders };
}

type Constructable<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export function Yield<T extends Constructable<any>>(token: string) {
  return (ctor: T) => {
    if (!YIELD_LIST[token]) {
      YIELD_LIST[token] = {
        overrideCtor: ctor,
      };
      DEFINED_YIELDERS.push(ctor.name);
    }
  };
}

export function Yieldable<T extends Constructable<any>>(token: string) {
  return (_ctor: T) => {
    if (YIELD_LIST[token]) {
      return class extends (YIELD_LIST[token].overrideCtor as T) {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
          super(...args);
        }
      };
    }
  };
}

Adding this before everything, to ensure proper behavior:
expectYieders(SpecificClassA).checkYielders();

Now base class, alongside Yield and Yieldable classes can be defined:
//-------class-a.ts--------
export const CLASS_A = 'CLASS_A_YIELD_TOKEN';
export class GeneralClassA {
  public value = 5;

  public showValue() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

//---specific-class-a.ts---
@Yield(CLASS_A)
export class SpecificClassA extends GeneralClassA {
  public override value = 10;
}

//----general-class-a.ts---
@Yieldable(CLASS_A)
export class ClassA extends GeneralClassA {}

